# Mixed unit conversion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, units

I have a silly question. I am not used to different unit systems and I am stuck with trivial problem. I have expression for energy of harmonic oscillator:
$$ 
\Delta E = \frac{1}{2}\Omega^2\Delta Q^2.
$$
I know that $\Delta E = 0.3358$ eV and $\Delta Q = 0.67\ \sqrt{\text{amu}}*\text{Angstrom}$. Then:
$$
\Omega = 1.22315\ \frac{\sqrt{\text{eV}}}{\sqrt{\text{amu}}*\text{Angstrom}}.
$$
How can I methodically convert these units to cm$^{-1}$ and eV. Can anyone explain to me logic of unit conversion. Furthermore I don't understand physical meaning of cm$^{-1}$.

Comment: cm^-1 means per centimetre. e.g. Kg per cm

Comment: Omega is already in terms of eV. To change to cm from Angstrom just treat it like a normal unit conversion if the other stuff was not there.